# fedora packages for enterprise linux

Tags: redhat, fedora, rpm, epel

There are a number of packages available on fedora that I would like to install on RHEL v6.x.  These packages do not appear to be available from RHEL (release, release-optional, or supplementary channels) or EPEL repos.

leptonica-devel
tesseract-devel
pdftk

pdftk appears to have a RPM available for download from their website and pdftk/tesseract are available at repoforge.  however, repoforge appears to be considered a problem repo: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories#head-a0dce03a04f29c2b0cabfcdfb488f2e7855c381b  It appears that i would need to install tesseract from source.

While i can try a patch work of RPM source or compile from source, I was hoping for a straight forward solution to this.  it was my understanding that EPEL provided access to all of the additional packages available to fedora but not available via the RHN repos.  Is that not the case?

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, EPEL offer only a subset of Fedora packages, unfortunately. Also, `pdftk` isn't available in F21 anymore.

Comment: thanks @Sven! i suspected that was the answer but didn't want to ignore the possibility i was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

PDF Labs maintain [their own pdftk binaries](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk-on-redhat-or-centos/) for EL 6. Why don't you just use those?

Comment: I will likely use those for pdftk.  I was just hoping for a straight forward way to pull down and install all of those packages ... akin to how easy it is on fedora or ubuntu